# Syntax error at or near "TYPE" in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I was trying to create Type but getting a Syntax error while doing it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ARR_HNW_ID AS VARRAY(50) OF INTEGER;
```

Can you please help me to resolve this Issue

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don’t believe OR REPLACE is valid syntax. You can CREATE or ALTER types but not REPLACE

Comment: I have tried with CREATE TYPE ARR_HNW_ID AS VARRAY(50) OF INTEGER;

Also but getting same error. Can you pls try ?

Answer (score 1):

Thera are multiple mistakes in your SQL:

1. There is no CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE syntax in PostgreSQL- take a look into [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html);
2. There is no type VARRAY in postgresql. If you need an array of integer just declare it like integer[].
3. What you are creating here is not a type but a [DOMAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html).

So basically you can simply use integer[] for your ARR_HNW_ID